# Is my open set a ball?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, convex-polytopes

Let $P$ be a polytope of dimension $n$, and let $\mathcal{C}$ be a polyhedral subdivision of $P$.  That means that $\mathcal{C}$ is a finite collection of polytopes whose union is $P$, such that the intersection of any two elements of $\mathcal{C}$ is a common face of both and is itself contained in $\mathcal{C}$.

Let $U$ be a convex open set that is contained in the interior of $P$, and let $A$ be the union of the relative interiors of all elements of $\mathcal{C}$ that touch $U$.  That is,
$$A := \bigcup_{\substack{Q\in \mathcal{C}\\ Q\cap U\neq \emptyset}} \operatorname{Int}(Q).$$
Note that $A$ is an open subset of the interior of $P$.

I would like to prove that $A$ is homeomorphic to a ball.  I would be just as happy to prove the following slightly weaker statement:
$$H_k(P,P\setminus A; \mathbb{Q}) \cong H_k(S^n; \mathbb{Q})$$ for all $k$.

Comment: Sorry this is a vague comment but I think discrete Morse theory (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Morse_theory) is a powerful tool for thinking about this kind of thing

Comment: Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the set of $Q$ you are taking union over to define $A$ (i.e., the $Q\in \mathcal{C}$ with $Q\cap U\neq \varnothing$). It seems that two important properties of $\mathcal{D}$ are: if $Q \in \mathcal{D}$ then $Q' \in \mathcal{D}$ for all $Q' \supset Q$; and if $Q$ is a face not on the boundary of $P$ with $Q' \in \mathcal{D}$ for all $Q' \supset Q$, then $Q \in \mathcal{D}$. Is it possible that these properties together already force your $A$ to be an open ball?

Comment: @SamHopkins I agree with your first statement; this is how I know that $A$ is open.  I don't think that the second statement is true, though.  For example, suppose that $P$ is a triangle, and $\mathcal{C}$ is a decomposition of $P$ into three triangles meeting at a single vertex in the middle (so the 1-skeleton is $K_4$).  Then it is possible to choose $U$ in such a say that $A$ consists of all three (open) triangles along with two of the three interior edges, but not the third.

Comment: I believe that the examples that I really care about *do* have the property that you describe, but I don't think this property follows from the hypotheses that I wrote in the question.

Comment: You are of course correct. I think the 2nd condition should at least be true for Q a vertex, and there may be ways to amend it in higher dimensions…

Comment: There's something about the definitions that I don't understand. Isn't $A$ disconnected, with one connected component for each $Q$?

Comment: @TimothyChow: maybe what's tripping you up is that the polyhedral complex $\mathcal{C}$ consists of faces (polytopes) of all dimensions. So the $\mathrm{Int}(Q)$ are *relatively* open sets (in $Q$), but their union forms a connected, open set.

Comment: @SamHopkins Ah yes, that makes sense! In my defense, the definition of $\cal C$ as written in the question does not say this, or use the word "complex."

Comment: @SamHopkins Oh, I see..."contained in $\cal C$" is supposed to mean that it's an *element* of $\cal C$ and not just that it's a subset of the union of the elements in $\cal C$.